# Change the ZIndex from two element

Tags: c#, wpf, z-index

I have a simple WPF application with two button. This is the code in my xaml file:

```
<Grid x:Name="grigliaPulsantiBody" Visibility="Visible"
        Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Panel.ZIndex="2"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!--PRIMA RIGA-->
    <Button x:Name="buttonLookNao" Content="Guarda NAO negli occhi" 
        Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
        Click="button_Click" Width="200" Height="100" Background="Red" />

    <Button x:Name="buttonLookParent" Content="Guarda Genitore negli occhi" 
        Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
        Click="button_Click" Width="200" Height="100" Background="Green"/>
    <!--FINE PRIMA RIGA-->
</Grid>
```

This is another control that I have create:

```
<local:RiepilogoEsercizio x:Name="riepilogoEsercizio" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
   Margin="0,-600,180,0" Panel.ZIndex="0"
   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Visibility="Hidden"/>
```

If I click on a button, the elemt "riepilogoEsercizio" change his ZIndex, so I have this

```
 Canvas.SetZIndex(riepilogoEsercizio, 999);
```

This is ok.
Now I want to set hidden this element. I use this code:

```
private void annullaBoxUscita(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
    myLoadBoxRiepilogoAnimation.From = 1.0;
    myLoadBoxRiepilogoAnimation.To = 0.0;
    //mostro la finestra dei risultati dell esercizio
    Storyboard.SetTargetName(myLoadBoxRiepilogoAnimation, riepilogoEsercizio.Name);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myLoadBoxRiepilogoAnimation, new PropertyPath(UIElement.OpacityProperty));
    //riepilogoEsercizio.labelTempo.Content = gioco.tempoEsecuzioneEsercizio;
    //riepilogoEsercizio.labelRisposteEsatte.Content = gioco.numeroRisposteCorrette;
    //riepilogoEsercizio.labelTentativi.Content = gioco._numeroTentativi;
    //riepilogoEsercizio.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

    Canvas.SetZIndex(riepilogoEsercizio, -800);
    Canvas.SetZIndex(grigliaPulsantiBody, 2);
    myStoryboardBoxRiepilogo.Begin(this);
    riepilogoEsercizio.IsEnabled = false;
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
    log.Error("ButtonEsci_Click: ", exc);
    this.Close();
    Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
    }
}
```

This code works, the element "riepilogoEsercizio" is hidden, but I can't click on second button "buttonLookParent", because the element "riepilogoEsercizio" is hidden but it is on this button. I try to change the ZIndex setting but not found.

Comment: Try setting its `Visiblity` to `Collapsed`.

Comment: Added that as answer. Please accept that so that others can learn from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `Visibility` to `Collapsed`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you have different panels, you have the `Canvas` and you have the `Grid`. In the grid you have the buttons, and in the canvas the controll you want to show/hide. The `Panel.Zindex` property works for the items that are in the same panel, so in this case decreasing the zindex value will doesn't work. A solution fo this is setting the `Visibility` property to `Collapsed` (like `:Nikhil Agrawal` said) in this way the visual item will behave like if it was not in the visual tree.

Hole this helps...